# Pytest asynchronous monkeypatch applies mock to all tests

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7

I have an asynchronous library `asynpg` which makes requests to an external database.

I want to have a test which mocks `syncpg.connect` to simulate a database connection, even when there *is* none:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_asyncpg(monkeypatch, mock_data):
    """ Patch asyncpg.connect """
    monkeypatch.setattr(asyncpg, "connect", mock_asyncio_connect(mock_data))
```

If I want to test using the mock I can include it:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_with_mock(mock_asyncpg):
```

But I'd also like to test with the real, unmocked, version of `asyncpg`, but `asyncpg` has been monkey-patched everywhere, and all tests see the monkey-patched version.

I assume this is happening because my tests are running asynchronously so they all see the same version of `asyncpg`

I see that there is [a library](https://github.com/hellysmile/asyncio_monkey) for asynchronous monkey patching, but I wonder if there's a better pattern I should be using. Maybe something to do with [CoroutineMock](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynctest.mock.html#asynctest.CoroutineMock)?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hoefling/3b807f3d495a47d54cc8af4299610c1f). Monkeypatching is reverted on test teardown. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for forcing me to look into this in much more detail, in an attempt to make a MRE. The problem was that my version of your `run()` function had `@alru_cache` (see [async_lru](https://github.com/aio-libs/async_lru)). The function therefore was returning a cached result! It wasn't the fault of `monkeypatch` after all!

Comment: Ah, I see - clearing the cache should indeed help in this case, e.g. with an autouse fixture [`clear_alru_cache`](https://gist.github.com/hoefling/3b807f3d495a47d54cc8af4299610c1f#file-test_aiomock-py-L31-L33), fixes the failing tests in the updated gist.

Comment: @hoefling Perfect. Thanks for helping out with this even though I didn't come up with a MWE.